# How to deleted the last character "/" in the input parameters

Tags: bash, shell

I want to format the input parameters.

The last character "/" should be deleted for each input.

For example,

```
sh test.sh one/ two three/
```

The result should be:

```
sh test.sh one two three
```

So, the content of  test.sh is like:

```
strb="/home/zz/"
echo ${strb%*/}  //it is OK

for arg in $*
do
  echo ${$arg%*/}  //it is fail
done
```

It is unlucky, ${$arg%*/} is wrong.

I have tried:

```
 echo ${\$arg\%*/}  and   echo ${\$arg%*/}    and   echo $\{$arg%*/\}
```

They are all fail. I don't know why, Who can help me?

Comment: It's `${arg%/}`.

Comment: @Aaron, what do you mean?

Comment: `${arg%/}` is the parameter expansion that will remove a trailing slash from the `arg` variable. See here : https://ideone.com/khtaSo

Comment: What are the args in `for arg in $*`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `${parameter%word}` expansion. Check out this [link](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to know more details about this:

Below is the basic script named `test.sh` to demonstrate the use of this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ${@%/}
```

You can invoke this script like this:

```
./test.sh one/ two/ three/
```

It should display `one two three`

Don't forget to make the script executable before invoking it. You can issue `chmod a+x test.sh`

Please note that `${@%/}` will only remove a single slash, not all trailing slashes. If you want to remove any number of trailing slashes, you can try this:

```
shopt -s extglob; echo "${@%%+(/)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to embed your variable `$arg`

It should be:

```sh
for arg in $*
do
  echo ${arg%*/}
done
```

Comment: I'd remove the `*` from the expansion too. It doesn't change anything here because `%` removes the shortest match from the end of the string, but that `*` can match the whole variable's content which doesn't look like something one would want